# Creating your own UTI for an iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios4, plist, file-format

The app I'm developing has a custom file format for its files, and I'd like to be able to use the "Open In ..." feature of iOS which lets users e.g. email each other a file and then open it directly in the app.

I've gotten as far as adding the CFBundleDocumentType stuff in the Info.plist file, but the problem is the LSItemContentTypes. [From what I've read](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html), I need to provide the actual file 
as a UTI, rather than just saying ".myfileextension", and I can't find a lot about how to create UTI's in a iOS app.

Anyone know?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will want to read up on the following topics from Apple:

[Adopting Uniform Type Identifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis.tasks/understand_utis_tasks.html)
[Introduction to Uniform Type Identifiers Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_intro/understand_utis_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001319)
[Declaring New Uniform Type Identifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_declare/understand_utis_declare.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001319-CH204-SW1)

> From the documentation:
>
> If your application uses proprietary data formats, you should declare them in the Info.plist file of your application bundle. Some guidelines:
>
> - Your UTI string must be unique.    Following the reverse-DNS format beginning with com.companyName is a simple way to ensure uniqueness.  While the system can support different UTI strings with the same specification, the reverse is not true.
> - If your code relies on third-party UTI types that may not be    present
>     on the system, you should    declare
>     those UTIs as imported types    in
>     your bundle.
> - Be sure to add conformance information if your proprietary type is a subtype of one or more existing types. In most cases you should not specify conformance to a nonpublic type, unless you are also declaring that type in your bundle. For a list of public and Apple-defined UTIs, see "System-Declared Uniform Type Identifiers"